# How to access albums, artists, playlists in Windows Phone Runtime?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Previously it was possible to access `Albums`, `Genres` etc. by using `MediaLibrary`

```
using(MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary())
{
    SongCollection songs = library.Songs;
    Song song = songs[0];
    MediaPlayer.Play(song);
}
```

But it is not available in Windows Runtime apps. What is the alternative way to access those data?

It's a Windows Phone Runtime app.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
var folder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
```

Use [StorageItemContentProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.storageitemcontentproperties.Aspx) on StorageFile and call [GetMusicPropertiesAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.storageitemcontentproperties.getmusicpropertiesasync.Aspx) it returns [MusicProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.musicproperties.Aspx).

```
StorageFolder musicFolder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await musicFolder.GetFilesAsync();

foreach (var file in fileList)
{
    MusicProperties musicProperties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine("Album: " + musicProperties.Album);
    Debug.WriteLine("Rating: " + musicProperties.Rating);
    Debug.WriteLine("Producers: " + musicProperties.Publisher);
}
```

Comment: It only gives files, like any other file. It's not possible to get playlists, plus I have to check each file and if it was a music file then get it's properties (album, artist etc..). lots of work for little gain

Comment: I would add some references: [question at MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/4e917f41-23ca-4277-ae6b-30917756c5c3/medialibrary-replacement?forum=winappswithcsharp), [guidelines at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452724.aspx#best_practices_for_using_playback_manager_in_an_app) and [link to KnownFolders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.musiclibrary.aspx)

Comment: @Romasz thanks. Problem still exists. I have to query files to sort them by album, artist etc.

Comment: @user3646098 Reading the answers at the qestion at MSDN, it seems that there is no direct repleacement of MediaLibrary.